# When are binary-all/Packages files read on debian repositories?

Tags: debian, apt

Debian repositories include the folder `binary-all` and inside them some `Packages` files, which mention independent-architecture packages.

However, it seems that at least `amd64` `apt` doesn't read the `binary-all/Packages` files and the `binary-amd64/Packages` files mention all `binary-all` packages.

When are the `binary-all/Packages` files read?